# Removing "space" in a data merge if not all names have titles to start with

Tags: grep, data-merge

I found a great reference on here for using Grep to remove a double space in a data merge if some names have a middle initial but others do not. But what do you do if the issue is at the start of the name. For example

<< Title >> << First >> << Last >>

<< address >>

Mr. and Mrs. John Smith

123 Apple Street

But the next person and or business does not have a title

( )Bob Brown

432 Peach Lane

0r

( )The Grant Group

795 Grape Circle

How to you remove the space before the Name field if there is no title.

I'm assuming you can use a different GREP formula to achieve this but I can't figure it out. Looking for a way to do in Indesign and not editing the OG Excel file.

This is the middle double space thread for reference. [How to auto delete a space left after a data merge in InDesign?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/105162/how-to-auto-delete-a-space-left-after-a-data-merge-in-indesign/105194#105194?newreg=c6e41098c3a949eba0e5822e079802a5)

Comment: I don't know Indesign GREP, but it seems that it uses regex for this, is `^\s` what you look for? This will match a whitespace in the start of a line

Comment: If you're just looking to remove single spaces at the beginning of paragraphs, I can confirm @Sergey's comment works, you need to GREP `^\s` and replace with nothing.

Comment: This is one of the many things in Adobe Indesigns data merge that's not well thought. As we are regular data merge users we searched for a solution solving this AND all of the other little issues stumbling upon and we ended with MyDataMerge for Mac. Tiny but very powerful app calling themselves " the missing interface for indesigns data merge". If you are a regular data merge user give it a try. In your case i"d just create a condition and if there's no title I won't render it at all and start the line with first name. Few clicks-done